# Programmatically place random digits into all textboxes of form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, textbox

My form looks like that:

[image]

As you see there are bunch of texboxes. I've created some loop for all textboxes to check if they are empty, null or if they conatin only digits.

Now what I want to do, is to generate random numbers and to place them into all empty textboxes (just as user types digit into textbox). How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) will help you generating random numbers:

```
var random = new Random();
var emptyTextBoxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                             .Where(txt => txt.Text.Length == 0);
foreach (var txt in emptyTextBoxes)
    txt.Text = random.Next(1, 1000).ToString();
```

Comment: @SaeedAmiri. you are wrong. txt.Text is never null, is an empty string. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a loop in place that can iterate all of the text boxes.  To the body of that loop, add something like

```
Random rnd = new Random();

// Do you loop here

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        textBox.Text = rnd.Next(10, 99).ToString(); // If you want numbers from 10 to 99

// End of your loop
```

If you always want to have the SAME values in the text boxes for some reason, you can specify a seed to Random by using the [Random(int seed)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) constructor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a random number. Use Math.Random along with another math operation to achieve this. Depends on what kind of you number you want (integers, positives, up to 100, whatever)
2. Loop at Form.Controls testing, for each control, if it **is Textbox**. And, for these cases, cast them and set the value like ((Textbox)control).Text = randomNumber

   ```
       int randomNumber;
       foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
       {
           randomNumber = //your randomMagic

           if (control is TextBox)
           {
               ((TextBox)control).Text = randomNumber;
           }
       }
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
       Random r = new Random();
       foreach (var ctrl in Controls)
       {
           var txtBoxCtrl = ctrl as TextBox;
           if (txtBoxCtrl != null)
           {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxCtrl.Text))
                   txtBoxCtrl.Text = r.Next().ToString();
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if(c.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
        {
            c.Text = random.Next().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```